# Xamarin forms global storage

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin forms. I am working on an app with 3 pages.
One of the pages has a listview. Clicking on a row takes you to another
page. I want to make this available for authenticated users only. You have to be
logged in to use this feature.

I have been looking online and no luck. Is there anything like session 
in xamarin forms? Is there anything I can use for storage which all pages
can have access to?

Any ideas/link will be appreciated

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/

Comment: There has to be other ways   rather than storing in a database right?

Comment: You can use the file system.

Comment: I just want to be able to store a Yes Or No value thats all. Yes - Authenticated and No - Not authenticated. Which file system?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason mentions, use Application.Current.Properties dictionary to store key pair values.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary

Fairly simple and doesn't require an additional dependency like Xam.Plugins.Settings.

Answer (score 0):

There's a cross platform settings plugin available from the Xamarin Component Store or as a nuget package. It's free and easy to use.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings/

It's as easy as creating a "Settings" class and then creating a getter and setter for your value like this:

```
public static bool Authenticated
{
   get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault<bool>(AuthenticatedKey, AuthenticatedDefaultValue); }
   set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue<bool>(AuthenticatedKey, value); }
}
```

It's well worth a look and super easy to implement for simple adhoc storage of values.

Comment: Hello @Jacob Joz can you provide a simple example of how this works for example for a cross platform session following the login?